# write file to multiple places (different file-systems)

Tags: filesystems, desktop-shortcuts

I want to create a sort of shortcut that when I write to it, it will write the same at X different places at the same time

For example KDenLive write `/home/user/multiPlaces/untitled.mp4`

So the OS write in `/home/user/externalHardDrive/untitled.mp4`, `/home/user/cloudPlace/untitled.mp4` and  `/home/user/local/untitled.mp4`

All of that at the same time whatever the program who ask to write in `/home/user/multiPlaces/`

Comment: Unless you actually need the physical writing, have you had a look at links? `ln` or `ln -s` will create links for you and give the impression of multiple files when there's actually just one.

Comment: Like you've seen, I write here in different physical places, whats the matter of doing that if it's not physical? As soon as I unplug one of those 3 places I lost the ability to access to the file. So obviously I ask for "a sort of shortcut" but not an actual shortcut, otherwise I should just rtfm and not posting a question

Comment: Right, if the file systems might be unplugged then links are no good. What do you want to happen when trying to write and one of the destinations is unplugged?

Comment: I didn't think about that, I'm opened to any solutions. Maybe just not write in this place and rising a warning who will not impeach the writing at the other available places? Or like you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to write to different disks which can be available just part of the time, what you need is *file synchronization*.

There are many options for this. [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) works for me although I don't sync local paths.

Comment: I haven't tested but it seems to be a good idea, not well integrated to Linux though

Comment: How is it not well integrated? It requires running a service which is something Linux does a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **hard-links** if these directories resides on the same filesystem:

```
ln /home/user/multiPlaces/untitled.mp4 /home/user/cloudPlace/untitled.mp4
ln /home/user/multiPlaces/untitled.mp4 /home/user/local/untitled.mp4
```

Where `/home/user/multiPlaces/untitled.mp4` and `/home/user/local/untitled.mp4` should not exist ; instead they will be generated during the creation of the hard link.

In this way they will be referenced directly to the oirginal **inode** and the deletion of the original will not reflect to the others.

Comment: Are you sure about the ones that should not exist? I think you made a mistake. If they're referenced to the original inode, should the other not be anything but shorcuts? So it's useless because I want the data to be effectively at different places

Comment: You will have an error `ln: failed to create hard link : file exists`